# Firebase / BigQuery - Huge difference in users count for one platform

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

When counting total users in Firebase Console and Bigquery export for project, we have a massive difference in users count:

| OS | Firebase (Total Users) | BigQuery (Users) | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Windows (Web) | 38k | 23k | 39% |
| Android | 21k | 24k | 15% |
| Ios | 10k | 12k | 20% |
| other platforms (Web) | 1,5k | 1k | ~50% |
| Total | 70k | 60k | 15% |

BigQuery query:

```sql
SELECT
  count(distinct user_pseudo_id),
  device.operating_system
FROM
  `{project}.events_*`
  where _TABLE_SUFFIX between "20210614" and "20210620"
GROUP BY
  device.operating_system;
```

I've read about Firebase approximation and HLL, but it shouldn't give that much difference?

Both platorms have filter on date, so it queries 1 week old data (14 june - 20 june).

Any suggestions, what can cause this difference and how to fix it?

Comment: How are you adding the data to Firestore and Big Query? Are you sure the data is being updated din both the places?

Comment: @Dharmaraj It's Firebase Analytics, not Firestore. Firebase collects data from mobile apps and web, we use Analytics SDK. Then, we set up BigQuery integration like this: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

Comment: Sorry for mistyping that. Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62652193/13130697) ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj yep. But I don't think this is the case, because BQ have somewhat similar numbers for Android and Web, but Firebase has totally different numbers, and this repeats in any time range